# Deleting all duplicates

Tags: mysql, delete, duplication

I am trying to delete all the duplicates but keeping single record only (shorter id).
Following query deletes duplicates but take lot of iterations to delete all copies and keeping original ones.

```
DELETE FROM emailTable WHERE id IN (
 SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id FROM emailTable GROUP BY email HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1 )
 ) AS q
)
```

Its MySQL.

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `emailTable` (
 `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=298872 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM emailTable WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT MIN(id) minID FROM emailTable    
    GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
  ) AS q
  WHERE minID=id
)
```

The above worked for my test of 50 emails (5 different emails duplicated 10 times).

You might need to add an index on the 'email' column:

```
ALTER TABLE emailTable ADD INDEX ind_email (email);
```

It might be a bit slow fro 250,000 rows. It was slow for me on a table that had 1.5million rows (properly indexed), which is how I came up with this strategy:

```
/* CREATE MEMORY TABLE TO HOUSE IDs of the MIN */
CREATE TABLE email_min (minID INT, PRIMARY KEY(minID)) ENGINE=Memory;

/* INSERT THE MINIMUM IDs */
INSERT INTO email_min SELECT id FROM email
    GROUP BY email HAVING MIN(id);

/* MAKE SURE YOU HAVE RIGHT INFO */
SELECT * FROM email 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM email_min WHERE minID=id)

/* DELETE FROM EMAIL */
DELETE FROM email 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM email_min WHERE minID=id)

/* IF ALL IS WELL, DROP MEMORY TABLE */
DROP TABLE email_min;
```

The benefit of the memory table is there's an index that is used (primary key on minID) that speeds up the process over a normal temporary table.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more streamlined deletion process:

```
CREATE TABLE emailUnique LIKE emailTable;
ALTER TABLE emailUnique ADD UNIQUE INDEX (email);
INSERT IGNORE INTO emailUnique SELECT * FROM emailTable;
SELECT * FROM emailUnique;
ALTER TABLE emailTable  RENAME emailTable_old;
ALTER TABLE emailUnique RENAME emailTable;
DROP TABLE emailTable_old;
```

Here is some sample data:

```
use test
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS emailTable;
CREATE TABLE `emailTable` (
 `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO emailTable (email) VALUES
('redwards@gmail.com'),
('redwards@gmail.com'),
('redwards@gmail.com'),
('redwards@gmail.com'),
('rolandoedwards@gmail.com'),
('rolandoedwards@gmail.com'),
('rolandoedwards@gmail.com'),
('red@gmail.com'),
('red@gmail.com'),
('red@gmail.com'),
('rolandoedwards@gmail.com'),
('rolandoedwards@gmail.com'),
('rolandoedwards@comcast.net'),
('rolandoedwards@comcast.net'),
('rolandoedwards@comcast.net');
SELECT * FROM emailTable;
```

I ran them. Here are the results:

```
mysql> use test
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS emailTable;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `emailTable` (
    ->  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    ->  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
    ->  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO emailTable (email) VALUES
    -> ('redwards@gmail.com'),
    -> ('redwards@gmail.com'),
    -> ('redwards@gmail.com'),
    -> ('redwards@gmail.com'),
    -> ('rolandoedwards@gmail.com'),
('rolandoedwards@comcast.net');
SELECT * FROM emailTable;
    -> ('rolandoedwards@gmail.com'),
    -> ('rolandoedwards@gmail.com'),
    -> ('red@gmail.com'),
    -> ('red@gmail.com'),
    -> ('red@gmail.com'),
    -> ('rolandoedwards@gmail.com'),
    -> ('rolandoedwards@gmail.com'),
    -> ('rolandoedwards@comcast.net'),
    -> ('rolandoedwards@comcast.net'),
    -> ('rolandoedwards@comcast.net');
Query OK, 15 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 15  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM emailTable;
+----+----------------------------+
| id | email                      |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | redwards@gmail.com         |
|  2 | redwards@gmail.com         |
|  3 | redwards@gmail.com         |
|  4 | redwards@gmail.com         |
|  5 | rolandoedwards@gmail.com   |
|  6 | rolandoedwards@gmail.com   |
|  7 | rolandoedwards@gmail.com   |
|  8 | red@gmail.com              |
|  9 | red@gmail.com              |
| 10 | red@gmail.com              |
| 11 | rolandoedwards@gmail.com   |
| 12 | rolandoedwards@gmail.com   |
| 13 | rolandoedwards@comcast.net |
| 14 | rolandoedwards@comcast.net |
| 15 | rolandoedwards@comcast.net |
+----+----------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE emailUnique LIKE emailTable;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE emailUnique ADD UNIQUE INDEX (email);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO emailUnique SELECT * FROM emailTable;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 15  Duplicates: 11  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM emailUnique;
+----+----------------------------+
| id | email                      |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | redwards@gmail.com         |
|  5 | rolandoedwards@gmail.com   |
|  8 | red@gmail.com              |
| 13 | rolandoedwards@comcast.net |
+----+----------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE emailTable  RENAME emailTable_old;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE emailUnique RENAME emailTable;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE emailTable_old;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As shown the emailTable will contain the first occurrence of each email address and the corresponding original id. For this example:

- IDs 1-4 have redwards@gmail.com, but only 1 was preserved.
- IDs 5-7,11,12 have rolandoedwards@gmail.com, but only 5 was preserved.
- IDs 8-10 have red@gmail.com, but only 8 was preserved.
- IDs 13-15 have rolandoedwards@comcast.net, but only 13 was preserved.

CAVEAT : [I answered a question similar to this concerning table deletion by means of a temp table approach](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/how-to-improve-innodb-delete-performance/1502#1502).

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a real quick Itzik solution.  This will work in SQL 2005 and greater.

```
WITH Dups AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY id) AS rn
  FROM dbo.emailTable
)
DELETE FROM Dups
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: OP is asking for MySQL

Comment: Yeah, just realized that; doh! Well, it's a great solution for MS SQL :)

Comment: Not bad to know about MS SQL too :p but at the moment looking for MySQL solution.