# MySQL - Slow InnoDB Write Speeds on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows, mysql-5.6, windows-10

I have Windows 10 bootcamped. I've installed the latest version of MySQL community server. I've also installed WordPress onto IIS. The MacBook has 16Gb of memory. Here is my config file

```
[client]
no-beep

# pipe
# socket=0.0
port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/Data
character-set-server=utf8
]default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="DESKTOP-F1OO1LC.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="DESKTOP-F1OO1LC-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="DESKTOP-F1OO1LC.err"
server-id=1
max_connections=151
query_cache_size=0
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=90M
thread_cache_size=10
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=171M
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=13M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size=7M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_log_file_size=48M
innodb_thread_concurrency=17
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_allowed_packet=4M
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=4161
query_cache_type=0
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong or do you need more information? I've tried following various guides but getting lost with all the options avilable.

Currently looking at a maximum of 20 writes per second!

Thanks

Comment: I've exactly the same issue.   Did you find the solution?  Rolandos reccomendations did nothing performance wise in my case.

Answer (score 6):

## RECOMMENDATION #1

You have [innodb_thread_concurrency](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) at 17. It really needs to be zero(0). Why ?

Rather than rehash stuff I wrote in the past, [please read the 7 posts I wrote about innodb_thread_concurrency being the best choice at 0](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A877%20innodb_thread_concurrency%20infinite).

## RECOMMENDATION #2

Using a small log buffer can be a bottleneck when writing to the redo logs.

Please read my 3-yr-old post [MySQL transaction size - how big is too big?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19569/mysql-transaction-size-how-big-is-too-big/19580#19580) why it should be bigger

I recommend [innodb_log_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size) being set to 128M

## RECOMMENDATION #3

The redo log needs to larger as well. You have

You have [innodb_log_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) at the default size for MySQL 5.6 : 48M

I recommend setting [innodb_log_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) = 1G.

## RECOMMENDATION #4

You have [flush_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_flush_time) set to 0. IMHO For any Windows OS, that's a big NO-NO.

The default is 1800 for Windows. I don't trust MySQL flushing to disk every 30 min in Windows.

I recommend [flush_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_flush_time) to 300 (every five(5) minutes)

## RECOMMENDATION #5

You should increase the IO threads

The defaults are

```
innodb_read_io_threads = 4
innodb_write_io_threads = 4
```

Percona Server's defaults are

```
innodb_read_io_threads = 8
innodb_write_io_threads = 8
```

You should start with 8 for both [innodb_read_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) and [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads).

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

I have so much more to recommend in terms of per-connection buffers : [How costly is opening and closing of a DB connection?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16969/how-costly-is-opening-and-closing-of-a-db-connection/16973#16973)

Comment: (5.6.6 changed the Windows default to 0 for flush_time.)

Comment: Slightly risky, but:  `innodb_doublewrite = OFF`.

Comment: All suggestions reduced process time 4 times! thank you!

Comment: Google brought me here. I also recommend to double-check the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` setting - in my installation it was set to `8M`, a value way too low. Setting it to `1G` remedied my MySQL performance issue.

Answer (score 3):

Gather up multiple queries into a single `BEGIN` ... `COMMIT` transaction.  This will cut down on the overhead and disk hits.

Don't do this blindly -- a million queries in a single transaction has other problems.  And error checks need to be handled differently; think `ROLLBACK`.